# Changing root password via script fails but reports success

Tags: centos, scripting, root, passwd

I have a project which requires me to make a script / sequence of commands to change the root password on a CentOS 7 installation.

I can assume the user that will be executing the script is already root.

Currently, I'm using the following, and getting a success message:

```
[root@localhost]# echo -e ‘password\npassword’ | (passwd --stdin root)
Changing password for user root.
passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
```

However, this doesn't actually change the password. Upon further inspection (manually setting the password), I notice the password `password` fails a dictionary check, but still reports success at the end:

```
[root@localhost]# passwd
Changing password for user root.
New password:
BAD PASSWORD: The password fails the dictionary check - it is based on a dictionary word
Retype new password:
passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
```

One possible solution is to try hashing the given password based on the method and salt provided in `/etc/shadow`, but I would like to avoid an overly complicated solution. I could also check whether the value in `/etc/shadow` actually changed, but that ignores the case in which the password is set to what it already was, which I would like to support.

Does anyone have a suggestion on trying to validate the password before actually setting it, or, preferably, getting the FULL output from `passwd` ?

Comment: The mechanism you're describing works fine for me (on CentOS 7). Have you checked to see whether /etc/shadow is updated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `passwd --stdin` you only need to send the password once. So correct version is

```
echo password | passwd --stdin
```

If your code sample is accurate then (a) you've got smart quotes there when you need straightforward forward quotes and (b) the password is probably being set to something like `password\npassword' (possibly with smart quotes either side).

Comment: Thank you! The problem was not exactly what I thought it was. It was exactly that the presence of the smart quotes were causing a wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

Making things work with the `passwd` command is impressive, since it traditionally is interactive and a pain to automate.  (Yay for the gnu generation for making it relatively painless.)  But if you're doing automation why not use commands that are more automation friendly, like [`chpasswd`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/centos/8/chpasswd/)?

```
echo root:password | chpasswd
```

will do what you're doing above.  And if you want to do 50 at once, just send more lines of `username:password`.